# Как программа работает с БД ?

Tags: c#, oracle

Привет ребята ! Допустим надо программа учёта машин в салоне (марка, модель, цена итп), например я пишу такую программу на C#+WinForms устанавливаю базу данных Оракл (ну особо не важно но мне надо Оракл) устанавливаю соединение со студией и этой базой, создаю таблички итп ... Вопрос : это получается я пишу клиент к базе Оракл а не полноценную автономную программу ? Тоесть если я перенесу эту программу на другой компьютер и попытаюсь внести данные в поле "марка авто" то программа выбросит ошибку ибо на этом компьютере нет установленной базы Оракл ?

Comment: да, Вам нужна будет база. Она не обязательно должна быть локальной - она может быть удаленной.

Comment: Если ваша программа неотделима от бд и представляет собой "клиент" к этой базе, то помимо файлов самой программы вам нужно позаботиться и о переносе копии базы. Если же с одной и той же базой работает энное количество клиентов,то она должна храниться на сервере, а ваше приложение сможет работать с ней с помощью обращений к этому серверу

Comment: @DreamChild, поняла большое спасибо !

Comment: @Алина_Климова если это реальный коммерческий проект, то доверьте дело проффесиональным программистам. (тк имеете дело с непосредсвенным влиянием на бизнес). Ели же же просто учебное задание - то уудачи в обучении.

Comment: @jimpanzer это просто учебное задание ! Просто хотела понять его до конца !

Comment: База данных это такая же программка как и та которую вы пишете/планируете написать, разница лишь в предоставляемом функционале (возможностях). Это так же означает что структура вашей базы данных и данные не перекочуют чудесным образом на другой компьютер вместе с вашей программой (не говоря уже о самой СУБД Оракл), именно поэтому придумали инсталляторы (которые ставят все необходимые пререквизиты для программ), как вариант ваша программа может при запуске просить указать ей настройки соединения к БД (в таком случае ответственность за наличие последней ложится на конечного пользователя)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно. Вы можете разместить СУБД на отдельном сервере. Тогда все ваши клиенты смогут работать с общей БД с использованием сети. В данном случае установка Oracle на каждый клиент не потребуется. Потребуется лишь сетевая доступность до сервера.

Comment: Отлично ! Большое спасибо ...

Answer (score 0):

СУБД ORACLE в принципе предназначена для коллективной работы многих клиентов на общей базе.
Она именно для этого заточена, именно в такой конфигурации СУБД ORACLE эффективна, удобна, надёжна. Поэтому ORACLE имеет серверную и клиентскую компоненту. 
В сети должен существовать хотя бы один сервер, к которому у клиента есть логин/пароль.
Для целей разработки-отладки сервер может быть установлен на клиентской машине. Но это не всегда удобно, и я бы не рекомендовал такую конфигурацию.
Устанавливать на каждый клиентский компьютер необходимо только небольшую клиентскую компоненту (SQL*NET).